# laravel fails to load videos from directory mapped as a volume in a docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm building a laravel app packaged as a docker container. Our home and product pages play HD videos and I want to avoid storing these videos in source control as they might change a bit frequently.

The idea is to put updated videos in a directory, add updated video names as a config property which can be picked up by blade when rendering the webpage. Adding hardcoded video file names in the code shared the but the `intro-xxxxxxxx` would come from a variable read from the .env file later on

```
<div class="background-holder overlay overlay-2 parallax d-none d-sm-block">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted">
        <source src="{{ asset('videos/intro-72126f2acfb477064fe31fcfaea14e79.webm') }}" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="{{ asset('videos/intro-01be5dedca0a6a6259c107e69d61af8d.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="{{ asset('videos/intro-213e0ed58dcc68f1089d0fc13408e586.ogv') }}" type="video/ogv" />
    </video>
</div>
```

now I'm mapping the directory with all these videos as a docker volume like so; in the Dockerfile I define a working directory

```
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www
```

and then in Docker compose I mount volumes

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: www
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: onex-webapp
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - /Users/anadi/Movies/OneX/:/var/www/public/videos
    networks:
      - onexweb
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: onex-webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true    
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/dev/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - onexweb
networks:
  onexweb:
    driver: bridge
```

when I check contents of the container I see this directory and the videos

```
❯ docker exec onex-webapp ls -l /var/www/public/videos
total 987168
-rw-r--r--  1 www www  64285377 Apr 23 08:18 fr-intro.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 www www  78065607 Apr 27 07:27 fr-intro.ogv
-rw-r--r--  1 www www   4212950 Apr 27 07:16 fr-intro.webm
-rw-rw-r--  1 www www  11110738 Oct 23  2018 fr3-intro.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 www www  22746906 Jun 23 07:43 isc-intro.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 www www  30409396 Jun 23 07:43 intro-01be5dedca0a6a6259c107e69d61af8d.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 www www  36319165 Jun 23 07:43 intro-213e0ed58dcc68f1089d0fc13408e586.ogv
-rw-r--r--  1 www www  22733111 Jun 23 07:43 intro-72126f2acfb477064fe31fcfaea14e79.webm
-rw-r--r--  1 www www  29432716 Apr 27 15:00 ta-intro.mov
-rw-r--r--  1 www www  18688528 Jul 17  2018 ta-intro.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 www www  21402515 Apr 29 05:30 ta-intro.ogv
-rw-r--r--  1 www www   9233096 Apr 29 05:38 ta-intro.webm
```

But when I access the pages I get a `404` error for these video URLs

`GET http://localhost:8000/videos/intro-72126f2acfb477064fe31fcfaea14e79.webm net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

If I give up the volumes way and add a symlink to these videos' directory under `public/videos` then I do not get a 404 error; curious what's causing this, and possible solutions. In production I will be packaging contents into docker container layers instead of mounting volumes hence the need to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved /videos as a directory config to nginx and mounted directory with videos as volume to nginx container, it works now.